# PHP function vs jQuery.each()

Tags: php, jquery

I was originally using PHP to loop through a bunch of case rules and apply a CSS style class to individual TD cells based on the value of the cell. PHP performed wonderfully, page loads almost instant. I wanted to experiment around with JavaScript as everyone says "don't do something in PHP if you can do it in JavaScript".

I am now using a .each() loop - but the problem is it takes 19.6 seconds to load and locks up the browser asking to stop running scripts - on a Core i7 4790k w/ 16 GBs of RAM! Terrible!

Is this a situation where using server-side looping is more efficient than JavaScript looping? Should I do the loop in PHP or JavaScript/jQuery?

Here is the jQuery code - if there is anything glaring wrong with it:

```
function inRange(value, low, high) {
if (value >= low && value <= high) { return value; }
else { return !value; }
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.jsColorTemp').each(function() {
        var tValue = $(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; }).text();
        switch(tValue) {
            case inRange(tValue, -999, -75): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB75', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -74, -70): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB70B74', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -69, -65): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB65B69', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -64, -60): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB60B64', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -59, -55): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB55B59', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -54, -50): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB50B54', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -49, -45): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB45B49', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -44, -40): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB40B44', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -39, -35): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB35B39', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -34, -30): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB30B34', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -29, -25): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB25B29', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -24, -20): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB20B24', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -19, -15): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB15B19', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -14, -10): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB10B14', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -9, -5): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6TB05B09', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, -4, 0): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T000B04', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 1, 4): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T004001', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 5, 9): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T009005', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 10, 14): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T014010', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 15, 19): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T019015', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 20, 24): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T024020', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 25, 29): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T029025', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 30, 32): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T032030', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 33, 34): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T034033', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 35, 39): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T039035', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 40, 44): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T044040', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 45, 49): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T049045', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 50, 54): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T054050', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 55, 59): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T059055', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 60, 64): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T064060', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 65, 69): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T069065', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 70, 74): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T074070', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 75, 79): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T079075', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 80, 84): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T084080', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 85, 89): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T089085', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 90, 94): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T094090', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 95, 99): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T099095', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 100, 104): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T104100', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 105, 109): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T109105', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 110, 114): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T114110', 0); break;
            case inRange(tValue, 115, 999): $(this).switchClass('jsColorTemp', 'C6T115', 0); break;
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: `JavaScript as everyone says "don't do something in PHP if you can do it in JavaScript".` - you can exclude me. I can imagine how large the script would be, data consumption and stuff. Imagine someone on mobile phone trying to download that. Although can be cached on the browser personally won't do everything I can do in javascript in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed it. So jQuery's "switchClass()" function is excruciatingly slow, even if you specify 0 second animation duration. Using "toggleClass()" works MUCH MUCH faster.